# PyCharm cannot find app.yaml when pushing to GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm

I can't deploy to app engine.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/appcfg.py -e my@gmail.com --passin --no_cookies update .
Usage: appcfg.py [options] update <directory> | [file, ...]

appcfg.py: error: Directory does not contain an app.yaml configuration file

Process finished with exit code 2
```

The project dir contains an app.yaml, which gae ca find when running the devserver.

Is this just another hopeless reinstall everything kind of problem?

Comment: Please run instead a simple shell script that shows the current working directory and its contents before running `appcfg.py` -- that will show you exactly what that "." is at the time appcfg.py run (I bet it's not what you think it is!).

Comment: The problem might be that `app.yaml` is not in your current directory while `appcfg.py` is in your path. I think the solution could be that you perform `cd` to the directory where you have the `app.yaml` and try it that way.

Comment: did you resolve this? I have the same problem

Comment: This *might* help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33132299/4495081