# Running app engine local development server from command prompt (v1.9.36) - Google Cloud complications (No module named portpicker)

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been running app engine local development server from the command prompt for 3 years without any issues (windows 7, 64bit). I just updated to v1.9.36 (download `960cfe2157c6e984802db4b0224cfe8273d727dc` from [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads)), and now when I run

```
dev_appserver.py [anything]
```

I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform/google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line
>   82, in 
>       _run_file(**file**, globals())   File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform/google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line
>   78, in _run_file
>       execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py",
>   line 37, in 
>       from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import dispatcher   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\dispatcher.py",
>   line 29, in 
>       from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import module   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py",
>   line 55, in 
>       from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import http_runtime   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\http_runtime.py",
>   line 53, in 
>       import portpicker ImportError: No module named portpicker

The strange thing is that if I use the SDK GUI, and hit the 'Run' button, it launches just fine, no errors. So my guess is that when running from the command line, it's using the version of 'dev_appserver.py' in the `Cloud SDK` folder, whereas the GUI is running the version in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\`. But my environment variables are:

`GAE_SDK_ROOT`: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine`

`PATH`: lots of other things, plus `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\`

And I dont see any reference to `Cloud SDK`, so I cant figure why the version in the folder would be run.

There are versions of dev_appserver.py in both `C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine`

Seems that in combining GAE SDK with Google Cloud, Google has made this more complicated than it used to be..

[UPDATE]

If I run `echo %PATH%` then among many other things, I see

`C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk..`

before

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\`

Which explains why it's running that version. The question now is: why is the former in my PATH if I havent set it in my user PATH variable? Where else is the Windows PATH manipulated? Presumable the Google Cloud SDK installer did this - how do I undo it?

Answer (score 1):

### New answer

I turns out that the Cloud SDK folder was in my *system path*, which is checked before the *user path*, so the version of dev_appserver.py in Cloud SDK was being executed, rather than the more up to date version in the app engine folder.

To fix this I simply removed the Cloud SDK from my system path, using the handy app detailed [here](https://superuser.com/a/583992/367478)

### Original answer

I worked out that if I rename the `Cloud SDK` folder in `C:\Program Files\Google` this fixes it. But that's a hacky fix, and presumably makes the `Cloud SDK` functionality unavailable (I dont *think* I currently need it).

So I'd still like a proper answer to this question. It seems that I need a way to control which version of dev_appserver.py gets run, and short of setting my environment variables (which I've already done) I dont know what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

Executing `dev_appserver.py [anything]` will launch the first `dev_appserver.py` executable encountered in your executable `PATH` environment, which appears to be not the one you expect :)

You have 2 options:

- update your `PATH` as needed
- execute the desired `dev_appserver.py` by specifying its full path:

> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py [anything]
> ```

This answer is somehow related: [appcfg.py not working in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131192/appcfg-py-not-working-in-command-line/33132299#33132299)

Comment: Right, but I have already set my PATH to include the correct folder, and to have no reference to the `Cloud SDK` folder, and yet somehow it's running the version in `Cloud SDK`, so something else must be going on.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the other answers, if you do not have the old standalone Google App Engine installed and only uses the Google SDK, you can also install portpicker with the following command line (assuming you have pip installed):

```
pip install portpicker
```