# Using Google app Engine for the first time to create a Guestbook using Python

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, github-for-windows

I'm having a frustrating issue with using google app engine for the first time. I'm trying to follow the beginner's tutorial offered on google page to create a Guestbook application using python on google cloud.

this is the link for the tutorial [Creating a Guestbook Application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/creating-guestbook#before-you-begin)

And this what I get after running this line `dev_appserver.py ./` in the Git Shell:

[image: error in the git shell]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not post text as images, instead copy/paste it (and format it as code or quotes) inside your post, to make it readable.

Comment: This answer *might* help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33132299/4495081

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the [directions for the guestbook](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/creating-guestbook#before-you-begin) and make sure you completed step #2 properly. It looks like you have not properly installed the App Engine SDK.

Also, after installation, you need to make sure that the App Engine SDK is in your system PATH. To do this:

1. Right click on My Computer
2. Click on Advanced System Settings on the left
3. Under the "Advanced" tab, click on Environment Variables
4. Edit the "PATH" environment variable
5. Make sure the Google SDK directory is listed there (it should probably be set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin`, but it may differ depending on your installation).