# Google App Engine: run dev_appserver.py app.yaml but nothing happens

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am following the official tutorial of google app engine "Getting Started with Flask on App Engine Standard Environment". The problem is that I cannot run the code successfully on local server. I typed:

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

in the command line and hit enter. Nothing happened and a new line was created. I was running the command in a virtual environment from the root directory where the app.yaml file is located. I have already added "[PATH_TO_CLOUD_SDK]/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py]" to the PATH environment variable.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Shouldn't just `[PATH_TO_CLOUD_SDK]/google-cloud-sdk/bin` be added to the path?

Comment: To rule the path out just invoke `dev_appserver.py` with its full path. Take a look at this answer (replacing `appcfg.py` with `dev_appserver.py`, it applies to both), it *might* help.

Comment: Thanks Dan. But I cannot see the link of the answer that you suggested. Can you post it again?

Comment: Duh! Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131192/appcfg-py-not-working-in-command-line/33132299#33132299

Comment: Thanks Dan. I am having a hard time understanding the second answer. Where does he change the settings of python interpreter? Please excuse me for asking here. I am not allowed to leave comments to other posts so I have to ask here.

Comment: That's only on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. The solution below works for me.
On windows command prompt write the following commands:

```
1 - cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin 
2 - python dev_appserver.py "C:\path\to\app.yaml"
```