# How do I run dev_appserver.py from within my feature file in behave python?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, python-behave

dev_appserver.py starts a local deployement of my appengine service. I want to run my tests on behave on this local service. I want to start the server within my tests first. How to run the dev_appsrrver.py app.yaml command in my behave feature file in the start ?

I have tried subprocess.run("python","dev_appserver.py") but it says couldnt find the file dev_appserver.py. I'm trying on windows.

Comment: Do you install python on your windows? and which version of python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're attempting to launch executables using `subprocess` methods typically you're not getting by default the same environment (execution path and current working directory) you're getting yourself in a shell/terminal. Which means you may need to reference files (both executables and regular files) using full paths in the list of arguments you pass to those methods.

Since the `subprocess.run()` execution complaints about the `dev_appserver.py` location it means it's finding python OK (you may still want to check that's it's the 2.7 version) and you need to provide the full path for `dev_appserver.py`, which depends on your OS and the SDK you use. On Linux, for example (sorry, I'm not a windows guy), the path is:

- `<GAE_SDK_dir>/dev_appserver.py` if using the GAE SDK
- `<gcloud_SDK_dir>/bin/dev_appserver.py` if using the gcloud SDK

You'll most likely need to pass the path to your GAE app's `app.yaml` file, too - as an argument to `dev_appserver.py`, otherwise you'll see it complain about inability to locate the app or its files (or just having things run badly - if the `app.yaml` file isn't specified `dev_appserver.py` attempt to auto-detect it and that doesn't work in all cases). I'd avoid complications and just specify the `app.yaml` file(s).

Also note that the `subprocess.run()` args should be a list. Something like this:

```
subprocess.run(['python', '<sdk_path_to>/dev_appserver.py', '<app_path_to>/app.yaml'])
```

See also [appcfg.py not working in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131192/appcfg-py-not-working-in-command-line/33132299#33132299) - the post is about a different executable, but the answers are equally applicable to `dev_appserver.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [App Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server):

> **To start the local development server:**
>
> 1. Run the `dev_appserver.py` command as follows from the directory that
>      contains your app's `app.yaml` configuration file:
>
>    Specify the directory
>      path to your app, for example:
>
>    `dev_appserver.py [PATH_TO_YOUR_APP]`.
>
>    Alternatively, you can specify the
>      configuration file of a specific service, for example:
>
>    `dev_appserver.py app.yaml`.
>
>    To change the port, you include the `--port`
>      option:
>
>    `dev_appserver.py --port=9999 [PATH_TO_YOUR_APP]`